# Remove files base on integer.name

Tags: bash

Ok what I am trying to do is very specific. I need some code that will remove files from a directory based on integer.name.

The files in the directory are listed like this

```
441.TERM (the # is actually a PID so it'll be random)
442.TERM
```

No matter what I always want to keep the first .TERM file & remove any .TERM file after that as no more than one should ever be created by my script, but it does happen sometimes due to some issues with the system I am scripting on. I only want it to effect my 000.TERM files any other files it finds in the directory can stay. So if directory contain any .TERM file an with an integer higher than the first one found then remove the .TERM files with higher integers.

PS. .TERM is not an extension just in case there is any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /your/path -name "*.TERM" | sort -t. -k1 -n | tail -n +2 | xargs -r rm
```

Let's break it down:

- `find /your/path -name "*.TERM"` will output a list of all `.TERM` files.

  You could also use `ls /your/path/*.TERM`, but you may find the output unpredictable. (Example: your implementation may have `-F` on by default, which would cause every socket to end in a `=` in the list.)
- `sort` sorts them by the first field (`-k1`) using a period as a separator (`-t.`). `-n` guarantees a numeric sort (such that 5 comes before 06).
- `tail -n +2` skips the first line and returns the rest
- `xargs rm` sends every output line to an `rm` command, removing them. `-r` skips running the `rm` if there's no output piped in, but is listed as a GNU extension.

The script as above is fairly robust for your needs, but may fail if you have so many files in the directory that they don't fit on one command line, and might get you into trouble if any matching filenames somehow contain a newline.

Comment: okay I'm gonna test it out :-) Thanks so much. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I got it working :-). I had a typo. Thank you very much. I'm going to test a lil more & make sure there are no issues.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to pass a `-r` in that last one, which should work even if you don't have any files there to remove. That's specific to the GNU version of xargs, though; you'll have to jump through an extra hoop or two if you're on some other flavor of *nix.

Comment: unfortunately when I put it in a script I got rm: /tmp/screens/S-mobile/TERM.12584= file doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know where it would be getting a `=` from the script above; I'm guessing it's a typo. In any case, StackOverflow comments aren't really great for debugging, so if you're online across the next hour or so let's try [this chat room](http://onetimechat.org/?301132888). (SO has its own chat feature, but you need 20 rep minimum to use it.)

Comment: I checked the director from a root login and the files show up in pink with 12483.TERM=